# Validation in ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) deprecated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I'm trying to use Validation in razor, but when I try to use the line

```
Validation.RequireFields("firstName", "lastName", "dateOfBirth");
```

visual studio tells me:

> 'System.Web.Helpers.Validation' is obsolete: '"Use
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.Unvalidated instead."'

and

> 'System.Web.Helpers.Validation' does not contain a definition for
>   'RequireFields'

but the most up to date reference I can find is http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/more-resources/asp-net-web-pages-api-reference#Validation and I don't really see how Unvalidated is supposed to do what I want.

How do I do validation?

Thanks!

Here's my web.config in case it's relevant:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="WebRole2" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do validation on your model with attributes:

```
public class MyModel
{
  [Required][StringLength(100)]
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

See this [excellent blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation) which explains it quite nicely. Also if the framework attributes don't fulfill your requirements, [this library](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) has a lot of extra attributes.