# 'Validation' does not contain a definition for 'Add'

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, google-cloud-platform, razor-pages

I just moved the content of a Razor Page (.cshtml-file) from an **ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework)** to a **Google Cloud Platform Project**. Now I receive the error in the title, along with a warning saying: **'Validation' is obsolete: 'Use System.Web.HttpRequest.Unvalidated instead'**.

I am still using .Net Framework as the target framework for the project. My guess is that the main difference is that the new Google Project uses MVC, which the other project does not. How might I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validation in ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813224/validation-in-asp-net-web-pages-razor-deprecated)

Comment: I have already seen that post, however, these errors does not appear in the other project and therefore I question wether the Validation is really absolete. But I will try the solution In the post you linked, thanks anyway.